# How to use defimage?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I think I followed the example literally, but it doesn't work. If I use `defimage` macro, the image descriptor isn't created, but when I use `create-image` will all the same arguments it does. Below is what I tried:

```
(defimage test ((:type png :file "/home/wvxvw/Projects/haxe-mode/trunk/ede/etc/images/interface.png")))
test                                    ; nil
(defimage test (:type png :file "/home/wvxvw/Projects/haxe-mode/trunk/ede/etc/images/interface.png"))
test                                    ; nil
(insert-image test)                     ; error
(setq test (create-image "/home/wvxvw/Projects/haxe-mode/trunk/ede/etc/images/interface.png" 'png nil))
(image :type png :file "/home/wvxvw/Projects/haxe-mode/trunk/ede/etc/images/interface.png")
(insert-image test)                     ; shows image
```

Any hints?

EDIT:

While the code above should illustrate the problem, the actual code that I'm trying to run is a bit more involved. Posting it just in case:

```
(require 'cl)

(defvar haxe-images-dir
  (concat (file-name-directory load-file-name) "etc/images/"))

(defmacro haxe-define-images (images)
  (append
   '(progn)
   (loop for image in images
         collect
         `(defimage ,(intern (concat "haxe-" image "-icon"))
            ((:type png :file
                    (concat haxe-images-dir ,(concat image ".png"))))))))

(haxe-define-images
 ("private" "public" "static" "instance" "inline"
  "volatile" "variable" "class" "interface" "macro"
  "enum" "deftype" "function"))
```

EDIT2:

This is how it finally works. Perhaps I had some parts of the code compiled and thus loaded from a different place or some such mystery...

```
(require 'cl)
(require 'haxe-project)

(defmacro haxe-define-images (images)
  (append
   `(progn)
   (loop for image in images
         with images-root = (concat haxe-install-dir "etc/images/")
         collect
         `(defimage ,(intern (concat "haxe-" image "-icon"))
            ((:type png :file
                    ,(concat images-root image ".png")))))))

(haxe-define-images 
 ("private" "public" "static" "instance" "inline"
  "volatile" "variable" "class" "interface" "macro"
  "enum" "deftype" "function"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a feature of `defimage` and other `def-` forms that they only set the variable if it is not already set. From the [documentation for `defvar`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/defvar.html):

> The `defvar` special form is similar to `setq` in that it sets the value of a variable. It is unlike `setq` in two ways: first, it only sets the value of the variable if the variable does not already have a value. If the variable already has a value, `defvar` does not override the existing value. Second, [...]

So I presume that you already have assigned something to `test`, so the `defimage` form does nothing. If you are in the process of editing the code, you can force a `def-` form to be evaluated by putting point on the form, and using the command [`eval-defun`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Eval.html) (<kbd>C-M-x</kbd>).

Note that you should use `defimage` only for declaring a global variable. For other cases (where you are going to be using the image locally), use [`find-image`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Images.html#index-find_002dimage-3834) instead.

---

In your updated code, your macro `haxe-define-images` fails to evaluate the expression `(concat haxe-images-dir ...)`. You can see this by expanding the macro:

```
 ELISP> (print (macroexpand-all '(haxe-define-images ("foo"))))
 (progn (defvar haxe-address-icon (find-image (quote ((:type png :file (concat haxe-images-dir "address.png"))))) nil))
```

This won't work because the `concat` is inside `quote` and so is not evaluated. You need to write something like this instead:

```
(defmacro haxe-define-images (images)
  (append
   '(progn)
   (loop for image in images
         collect
         `(defimage ,(intern (concat "haxe-" image "-icon"))
            ((:type png :file
                    ,(concat haxe-images-dir image ".png")))))))
```

(If you actually intend to delay evaluation of `haxe-images-dir` then the macro will need to be more complex than this, but I'm sure you can figure it out from here.)

Comment: Can you show your updated code? Give both the `create-image` call that works, and the `find-image` call that fails.